# Visual studio not showing method/variables/tips anymore

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, configuration

When writing a variable in visual studio or whatsoever it used to show a window displaying the possible options. If for example I wrote `Label.` it would show a window with the various options that I could use with the label. Since Yesterday this Window is gone and I don't seem to be able to find how to activate it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to toggle this in the following menu:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> 'Auto list members'

Comment: Is there possibly another add-in intercepting the intellisense?

Comment: nope, i dont have any additional programs/add-ins installed. it just stopped working Yesterday.

Comment: Does any of this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236179/visual-studio-2012-2013-slow-list-members-intellisense

Comment: I tried to disable your setting, restart the program, then reenable the setting and restart the program and now its workign! thanks for your help!

Comment: Tried your last suggestion sharkyenergy but now I'm getting a weird incomplete list that looks to be part of ReSharper, which I have installed.